# How to add a detailed view to a page view controller on button click

Tags: ios, swift, uipageviewcontroller, xcode7-beta3

I am doing a project using page view which presents a label and a picture of a product. My idea is to put a button on each page which will present another view controller with detailed information about the product on the current page. The problem is that I can't come up with an idea how to achieve this. I will be very thankful if you help me achieve this.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I think you just new started to develop iOS Apps. So I would not give the code snippet for your project but I can give you a tip about your achieve.

You want to create Master - Detail Page View. It's very common pattern in iOS Development.

You can create Master-Detail Application theme in xCode. If you want to another information, you can search on Google or StackOverFlow with master-detail keyword.

Comment: I know that I have to create a master - detail page view but the problem is that I don't know where to perform the segue and how to pass the data

Comment: If you create your project with Master - Detail pattern in xCode, you will see perform segue method and data transfer codes for transfer data between two view controller. I can't teach you from scratch you should ask google or watch videos from youtube.

This video can help you to learn data transfer.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=guSYMPaXLaw